# Error installing firebird RDBMS bindings package on windows

Tags: python, firebird

I am installing the fdb package on windows

This package

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fdb

and i get this error

```
C:\fdb>python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    from fdb import __version__
  File "C:\fdb\fdb\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from fdb.fbcore import *
  File "C:\fdb\fdb\fbcore.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import ibase
  File "C:\fdb\fdb\ibase.py", line 43, in <module>
    fb_library = WinDLL(fb_library_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found
```

Has anyone encountered this error before?.I have the python driver for firebird installed and also the python driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it. After installing the Firebird super server, copy fbclient.dll (you will find it under C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\bin) and paste it under C:\WINDOWS

If your problem persists, there is a hack I found on the firebird-python mailing list on Yahoo here: [Re: Again: can't install fdb](http://fb-list-archive.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/firebird-python/2013/1/638.html)

Comment: This could have been done as part of the Firebird installation itself (there is an option 'copy client library to windows folder' or something like that. The other option would have been to add the firebird `bin` folder to the `PATH`. Also the `System32` (32 bit on 32 bit system, 64 bit on 64 bit system) and/or `SysWOW64` (32 bit on 64 bit system) folder is probably a better location than directly in the Windows folder.

Comment: I must have missed that part 'copy client library to windows folder'  if there was one.I did add the bin folder to the path but i never restarted my machine after installing firebird.